# How should I combine two implementations which do the same thing but under different contexts and have different method signatures?

Tags: java, oop

I might be trying to too hard to combine something that cannot be combined. I have 2 classes that do the same thing called createOrReturnFoo. two different classes that implement this process but they do it in different ways and use different parameters. I would liked to combine them under the same interface but I'm not sure its possible.

```
public class Foo {
    private final String data;

    public Foo(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

public class ClassA {
    HashMap<String, Foo> FooAMap = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<String, Foo> FooBMap = new HashMap<>();

    public ClassA() {
        FooAMap = new HashMap<>();
        FooBMap = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public Foo createOrReturnFoo(boolean Amap, String fooId) {
        HashMap<String, Foo> mapToUse = Amap ? FooAMap : FooBMap;
        if (mapToUse.containsKey(fooId)) {
            return mapToUse.get(fooId);
        } else {
            Foo foo = new Foo("data");
            mapToUse.put(fooId, foo);
            return foo;
        }
    }
}

public class ClassB {
    Repository fooRepository;
    public ClassB() {
        fooRepository = new fooRepository();
    }

    public Foo createOrReturnFoo(Date fooDate) {
        Foo foo = fooRepository.findByDate(fooDate);
        if (foo != null) {
            return foo;
        } else {
            foo = new Foo("data");
            fooRepository.save(foo);
            return foo;
        }
    }
}
```

It might be hard to tell from the generic example but both ClassA and B "do" the same thing, either retrieve Foo from a store, or create and new one. But they are used in different contexts. for example in ClassA I need to a boolean to see which store to use in the first place.

Comment: You can always make the method parameter an object, let's say `record Data(boolean Amap, String fooId, Date fooDate){}`, and each implementation uses whatever data it needs, but this does not seem like a good idea. From the example the two processes do not look interchangeable - if you were to replace `ClassA` with `ClassB` (assuming they already implement same interface), or vice versa, it seems as if this would break the process.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head. Likewise I could make an interface that defines both signatures and have a dummy implementation. But then it still requires the other classes to know which one is the right method. So it works but isn’t ideal.

Comment: These methods may look similar in shape but what they have in common is too trivial to deserve an abstraction for the uncommon parts. By the way, you can rewrite `ClassA`’s method to the one-liner `return (Amap? FooAMap: FooBMap).computeIfAbsent(fooId, key -> new Foo("data"));` Then, the two methods have nothing in common anymore.

Comment: Do both methods create the same Foo? Then running one before the other might reveal different results - it is just not equivalent. But without more details it is hard to say how to move on. You will have to take some decision here.